# Error when modifying app shortcut using Powershell

Tags: powershell, shortcut, argumentexception

I have following Powershell code that make Chrome always opened using default profile when clicked on pinned icon on Taskbar:

```bsh
$shortcutPath = "$($Env:APPDATA)\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\Google Chrome.lnk"
$shell = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
$shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut($shortcutPath)  ## Open the lnk
$shortcut.TargetPath

if ($shortcut.TargetPath.EndsWith("chrome.exe")) {
  $shortcut.TargetPath = """$($shortcut.TargetPath)"" --profile-directory=""Default"""
  $shortcut.Save()  ## Save
}
```

When executing it, the `if` statement throw below error:

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
At line:2 char:31
+   $shortcut.TargetPath = """$($shortcut.TargetPath)"" --profile-direc ...
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
```

Why I get above error? And how to fix it? Thank!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not add the parameter(s) to the `TargetPath` property, but instead set these in the shortcut's `Arguments` property:

```
$shortcutPath = "$($Env:APPDATA)\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\Google Chrome.lnk"
$shell = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
$shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut($shortcutPath)  ## Open the lnk

Write-Host "TargetPath = $($shortcut.TargetPath)"
Write-Host "Arguments  = $($shortcut.Arguments)"

if ($shortcut.Arguments -ne '--profile-directory="Default"' ) {
  $shortcut.Arguments = '--profile-directory="Default"'
  $shortcut.Save()  ## Save
}

# Important, always clean-up COM objects when done
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($shortcut)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($shell)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Awesome! I don't see the `Arguments` field when I edit the shortcut using UI, so I don't know there is an option for it. And I pretty like the GC as well, you're surely know about PS and COM very well!

Comment: @TuyenPham Ha, not well enough it seems, because I forgot to do a `ReleaseComObject` on the `$shell` itself earlier. I've put that line in now as well.